# Next Invoice Number and save copy as excel or pdf

Tags: excel, invoice, vba

I am trying to get my excel invoice to generate the next invoice number and save a copy of the invoice to a file when a button is pushed. 
I used this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tj_Ce7LS1Ok
and several forums but it is not working.

I assigned this code to a button created in excel:

```
Sub NextInvoice()
    Range("E5").Value = Range("E5").Value + 1
End Sub

Sub SaveInvWithNewName()
    Dim NewFN As Variant
    ' Copy Invoice to a new workbook
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    NewFW = "C:\Users\Jessica\Desktop\Grow Work\Invoices\Inv" & Range("E5").Value & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs NewFN, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    NextInvoice
End Sub
```

It says "Runtime Error '1004'" when I hit the button. The invoice number will change however the error occurs when a copy tries to save.

Comment: `Dim NewFN As String`. The `.SaveAs` Method is expecting an string value in the first argument and it does not recognize the `Variant` type you have assigned to `NewFN`

Comment: Please always use Option Explicit when coding in VBA. It will save a lot of hassles.

Answer (score 0):

I used this same code. I found that issue due to having merged cells. I unmerged the cells and amended my form. Once I had removed the merged cells it was all good.

Answer (score 0):

I initially had the same problem, and found that I had merged cells that were causing problems, I fixed specifying the merged cells and repaired the issue. I see this is an old post, but I use the same code in my invoices and it works flawlessly. I have it setup to print two copies, "save as" XLSX copy to provide bookkeeping redundancy, clear the contents and advance the invoice number, then save the new "empty" invoice with the new number. Here is my coding, feel free to use any part of it that you would like.

```
    Sub NewInvoice()

Range("E3").Value = Range("E3").Value + 1
Range("C5:C6").ClearContents
Range("E5:F6").ClearContents
Range("B7:C12").ClearContents
Range("E7:F12").ClearContents
Range("A14:E23").ClearContents
Range("A25:E36").ClearContents
End Sub

Sub SaveInvWithNewName()
    Dim NewFN As Variant
    ' Copy Invoice to a new workbook
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    NewFN = "E:\Bee Lick Gunworks LLC\Customer Invoices\" & Range("E3").Value & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs NewFN, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Print2    
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    NewInvoice
    ActiveWorkbook.Save     
End Sub

Sub Print2()
For I = 1 To 2
ActiveSheet.PrintOut
Next I
End Sub
```

The cells specified are specific to my invoice, change them to match your invoice. i.e. "E3" is my invoice number, "C5:C6" and "E5"F6" are dates, "B7:C12" are customer demographics, etc.

I have created a shape, and assigned the "SaveInvWithNewName" macro to it, click one button and go...

Best wishes,
Greg